# How efficient is it to return very large data in F#?

Tags: functional-programming, f#, return-value, heap-memory, stack-memory

Suppose we have a Matrix class in F# and you overload the (+) operator. Then, we will have something like this:

```
type Matrix(n : int, m : int) = 
    ...
    static member (+) (A : Matrix, B : Matrix) = 
        let res = new Matrix(A.Dim1, A.Dim2) // suppose A and B have the same dimension
        ... // compute here the sum
        res
```

Comparing to C/C++, we would have something like this:

```
static const Matrix operator+(const Matrix& A, const Matrix& B)
{
    Matrix res(A.Dim1(), A.Dim2());
    ... // compute here the sum
    return res;
}
```

Now, observe that in F#, the matrix `res` is allocated in the **heap memory**, in contrast with the C++ version, that allocates `res` in the **stack memory**.

So far so good. Observe what happens when we want a "*reference*" to the result of the sum operation in both versions:

```
Matrix result = A + B; // deep copy in C++ (because res has to be destroyed after its return)

let result = A + B // shallow copy in F# (res was allocated in the heap memory)
```

Am I missing something here or the (+) operator in F# ends up being more efficient than its counterpart in C/C++, because of the shallow and deep copy behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Usually, it is faster to keep data on the stack. And commercial-grade C++ compilers will often use the ["return value optimization"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

But until you start to actually measure the performance, you will never know which is faster. There are too many factors involved.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I never heard about return value optimization. Note that I could work with pointers in the C++ implementation, but this would be cumbersome and resulting in a very ugly and it would be not as straightforward as the one I provided. With return value optimization, it seems that the compiler does this low-level job for you. Very interesting. I would like to know if this is possible in C# and F#.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, F# (as C# and VB.NET) passes objects (class instances) by reference (so no copies created), if you use structs (in C#, not sure if you can create such a thing in F#) then they are passed by value (thus copies are created). Note that in C++ you can do it both ways too. But, yes, the way you propose your example, the F# solution is going to be more efficient.

Alas, somebody would probably point out that if you make Matrix a mutable object then you'll be even more performant (as no new Matrix objects need to be created), but then you loose all of the goodness of immutability.

Answer (score 2):

.NET has reference and value types, and value types are allocated on the stack (unless they're part of a reference type, but let's not get carried away). In C# you would declare them with the `class` and `struct` keywords, respectively.

While this is not really part of the F# type declaration semantics, you can tell the compiler to create a particular type as a value type, by using the `[<Struct>]` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the [<Struct>] attribute, one more thing I learn trying to answer at stackoverflow. :-)